# Testcafe ignore overlaying element

Tags: reactjs, testing, canvas, automated-tests, testcafe

---

Problem: Cannot find Canvas due to overlaying polyline that follows cursor position inside the canvas.

Target element: Canvas

Overlaying element: polyline

Possible solution: Ignore polyline element??

---

Explanation:

This polyline blocks the underlying element (canvas) which causes TestCafe to not see the canvas on click.

TestCafe waits until the waiting time is over and will click on the given location when done waiting. This causes the test to succeed. But there is a big delay because of this.

Adjusting the waiting time cannot be done due to other steps in the test that need the waiting time.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the project due to the medical environment.

Please help.

---

Kind regards

Comment: As I understand from your description, you have html canvas and want to click on it. However some polyline element follows the cursor and prevents a click. 
Is this polyline a separate html element - SVG or what? Even if you cannot share your project, it would be nice to prepare a sample project that demonstrates the issue. 
Since the issue is unclear, I can only recommend you take a loot at https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/ and hide the polyline if it's a separate element.

Comment: That is indeed true! The element gets placed after the first click which prevents testcafe from seeing the canvas that should be clicked. So you're telling me i can fix this problem with the clientfunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide an element by using your [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/) in this way:

```js
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page`https://google.com`;

test('test', async t => {
    const hideElement = ClientFunction(() => {
        document.querySelector('#tsf').style.display = 'none';
//NOTE: (document.querySelector('#tsf') as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none';
    });

    await hideElement();

    await t.debug();
});
```

Comment: Sounds great! only problem I've left is a Typescript Error that tells me: "Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.". I've tried some different approaches but i can't seem to make it work. Appreciate the answer btw!

Comment: The error occurs because the `querySelector` method returns the object of the `Element` type, which does not contain the 'style' property. One of possible solutions is to cast the `Element` type to the `HTMLElement` type. I've added a note to @V.Airich's code. Take a look.